# Unix advanced file permissions on web server

Tags: apache2, php, permissions, acl

I've got 3 folders that contain PHP scripts:

```
- core 
- custom_modules_1 (cm1)
- custom_modules_2 (cm2)
```

The core is executed by Apache and includes (require_once) files from either cm1 or cm2. It never includes cm1 & cm2 at the same time.

But the problem occurs when cm1 includes a file from cm2, which should be prevented, but how?

I'm running a VPS CentOS server with cPanel, so ACL is probably not an option since it could break cPanel.

Comment: I feel this as programming related question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you for your answers, but the only way I've managed to force the wanted restrictions was using php auto_prepend_file to append a file that does certain checks inside every php file that is included.

Answer (score 0):

This cannot be solved with permissions. You will need to add sentinel code to each script in order to prevent cross-inclusion.

Answer (score 0):

There are a number of ways to solve this depending on the details of your exact requirements (not clear from post).

- use different include paths for scripts depending on where they will source the modules from (with custom_modules_1 or custom_modules_1 as part of the path)
- use open_basedir to restrict access to specific directories
- use different ownership on the different filesets and enforce access permissions using suphp